# knockout.js - mapping plugin - how to add ko.computed function

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to get this to work but am not doing something right.
I am using knockout, taking a json response and mapping it for a checkout cart, what I am not able to do is add a function after to add the sum of the product prices. see below for an idea of what I am trying to do,

full fiddle is here.. http://jsfiddle.net/justayles/Jeaua/26/

```
var jsonCart = {
    "globalshipping": 1.00,
    "globaltax": 5.00,
    "productitem": [
    {
        "img": '/Content/img/notavailable.jpg',
        "produrl": 'http://www.google.com',
        "prodtitle": 'Product1',
        "opt1": 'colour',
        "opt2": 'size',
        "qty": 3,
        "unitprice": 10.00,
        "shippingcost": 0.00,
        "like": true,
        "likediscount": 10,
        "taxable": true
    },
    {
        "img": '/Content/img/notavailable.jpg',
        "produrl": 'http://www.google.com',
        "prodtitle": 'Product1',
        "opt1": 'colour',
        "opt2": 'size',
        "qty": 1,
        "unitprice": 33.00,
        "shippingcost": 0.00,
        "like": false,
        "likediscount": 0,
        "taxable": false
    },
    {
        "img": '/Content/img/notavailable.jpg',
        "produrl": 'http://www.yahoo.com',
        "prodtitle": 'Product1',
        "opt1": 'colour',
        "opt2": 'size',
        "qty": 5,
        "unitprice": 21.00,
        "shippingcost": 0.00,
        "like": true,
        "likediscount": 10,
        "taxable": true
    }
    ]
};

var mappingOptions = {
    'productitem': {
        // overriding the default creation / initialization code
        create: function (options) {

            return (new (function () {

                // setup the computed binding
                this.calcPrice = ko.computed(function () {
                    return this.unitprice() * this.qty();
                }, this);

                ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data, {}, this);
            })(/* call the ctor here */));
        }
    }
};


var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(jsonCart, mappingOptions );

viewModel.grandTotal = ko.computed(function() {
    var result = 0;
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.productitem, function(item) {
        result += item.calcPrice;
    });
    return result;
}, viewModel);

console.log(viewModel);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: +1 for supplying a working fiddle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/Jeaua/27/

You forgot parentheses on your `productitem` and `calcPrice` observables. Remember, `ko.mapping` turns arrays into observable arrays and values into observable values. These need to be called as functions in order to retrieve their actual value.

```
viewModel.grandTotal = ko.computed(function() {
        var result = 0;
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.productitem() /* parentheses */, function(item) {
            result += item.calcPrice(); /* parentheses */
        });
        return result;
}, viewModel);
```

Comment: The link in the fiddle for knockout.mapping.js is now 404ing.  But on the External Resources tab of the JSFiddle, the bad link can be replaced with https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.js